# How can I query using like on json field in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, json, like

I've set up the following DB Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/mzsp-4tg

How should I make a correct SQL query to use `like` on `geo_json` field of `json` type to get table records with string matching coordinates combination `%30.504106925781265,50.43731985018662%` ?

Comment: Have you considered _not_ storing coordinates as JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store or convert the column to `jsonb` then you can use JSONpath

```
SELECT *
FROM polygon_versions
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(
  geo_json,
  '$.geoJSON.geometry.coordinates[*] ? (@[0] == 30.504106925781265 && @[1] == 50.43731985018662)');
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/uH8dzBVI)

Comment: How can I fix the following ERROR:  function jsonb_path_exists(json, unknown) does not exist
LINE 3: WHERE jsonb_path_exists(
              ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 38

Comment: I have the following PostgreSQL version: PostgreSQL 14.7 (Debian 14.7-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit

Comment: Is the column `json` or `jsonb`? This only works with `jsonb` so either change the column's data type, or convert it like this `WHERE jsonb_path_exists(geo_json::jsonb, ...`